# Why doesn't my table row appear when the button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, css, html-table, tr

Just trying to have a new drop down row to enter some data on a form. Should be simple, but the drop down shows in the first cell only, even when using `colspan=5`.

Or is there a better way?  Thx for any help.

```html
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=7 border=1>
  <tr bgcolor=#efefef>
    <td></td>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>DATA</td>
    <td>MORE DATA</td>
    <td>Method</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button onclick="javascript:showElement('abcdata')" style="padding:4px" class=verd8> SHOW NEW ROW </button>
    </td>
    <td>Jan 22, 2022</td>
    <td>SOME DATA</td>
    <td>SOME MORE</td>
    <td>BUTTONDROP</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="abcdata" style="display:none;">
    <td colspan=5>
      SHOW NEW ROW ACROSS ALL CELLS : sfdgsdfgs hlahhfa la dfl dfljhsd flhsd flhsdf lhdsfh asf alhd a</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td colspan=5>
  ADDED THIS tr/td IN EDIT : NOTHING HIDDEN.... DOES IT SHOW ALL ACROSS?? YES IT DOES
  </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: You have `style="display:none;"` on the cell. What do you expect? Maybe if you include your JavaScript function we can see the problem.

Comment: Javascript is in the button : show element is usually supported without need for additional JS.  I use it everywhere. <button onclick="javascript:showElement('abcdata')" style="padding:4px" class=verd8> SHOW NEW ROW </button> This works to show the ROW... But it only shows in 1st cell not across all 10.  Firefox Browser

Comment: @Merle_the_Pearl the problem is in `showElement`, which we cannot help you with since we have no clue what that is

Comment: `showElement` isn't a native part of Javascript in the browser. A quick google search tells me that it's likely from the library that [code.org's App Lab IDE](https://studio.code.org/docs/applab/showElement/) provides. It's not going to work without that environment and it may only work with elements created using their library.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I don't know where you got `showElement` from, but the simplest way to unhide your row is going to be `abcdata.style.display=''`

```html
<button onclick="abcdata.style.display=''"
```

```html
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=7 border=1>
  <tr bgcolor=#efefef>
    <td></td>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>DATA</td>
    <td>MORE DATA</td>
    <td>Method</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button onclick="abcdata.style.display=''" style="padding:4px" class=verd8> SHOW NEW ROW </button>
    </td>
    <td>Jan 22, 2022</td>
    <td>SOME DATA</td>
    <td>SOME MORE</td>
    <td>BUTTONDROP</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="abcdata" style="display:none;">
    <td colspan=5>
      SHOW NEW ROW ACROSS ALL CELLS : sfdgsdfgs hlahhfa la dfl dfljhsd flhsd flhsdf lhdsfh asf alhd a</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function showElement(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).classList.remove('hidden');
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=7 border=1>
  <tr bgcolor=#efefef>
    <td></td>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>DATA</td>
    <td>MORE DATA</td>
    <td>Method</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button onclick="javascript:showElement('abcdata')" style="padding:4px" class=verd8> SHOW NEW ROW </button>
    </td>
    <td>Jan 22, 2022</td>
    <td>SOME DATA</td>
    <td>SOME MORE</td>
    <td>BUTTONDROP</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="abcdata" class="hidden" >
    <td colspan=5>
      SHOW NEW ROW ACROSS ALL CELLS : sfdgsdfgs hlahhfa la dfl dfljhsd flhsd flhsdf lhdsfh asf alhd a</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I don't see your code but I guess you use display: block in order to display the td.

I suggest you to add css class that is called hidden.

Add it to the element you want to hide.

When you want to display the element, remove it.

P.S.
I don't suggest to change specific properties via JS (if it's not necessary).

Comment: Still shows only in the 1st cell... Does not span through all the cells as new clean row.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be implying that `showElement()` is a native JavaScript function. It isn't. If we add the function your code works.

My guess is that you're accustomed to working on projects where some utility functions are provided by another script or library.

```html
<script>
  function showElement(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'table-row'; 
    // or just '' to make it more generic
  }
</script>

<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=7 border=1>
  <tr bgcolor=#efefef>
    <td></td>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>DATA</td>
    <td>MORE DATA</td>
    <td>Method</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button onclick="javascript:showElement('abcdata')" style="padding:4px" class=verd8> SHOW NEW ROW </button>
    </td>
    <td>Jan 22, 2022</td>
    <td>SOME DATA</td>
    <td>SOME MORE</td>
    <td>BUTTONDROP</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="abcdata" style="display:none;">
    <td colspan=5>
      SHOW NEW ROW ACROSS ALL CELLS : sfdgsdfgs hlahhfa la dfl dfljhsd flhsd flhsdf lhdsfh asf alhd a</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```